# Can't genetaye pdf with unicode character by kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(...) in spring project

Tags: javascript, pdf, unicode, kendo-ui, thymeleaf

I am doing a project where I want to generate pdf from HTML. I can generate pdf from HTML successfully. But the problem is in HTML page unicode characters are shown, but when the pdf is generated those unicode characters are not shown. It has become box. My java-script code for generating pdf is

```
<script>
    kendo.pdf.defineFont({
        "DejaVu Sans":
            "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2019.1.220/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans.ttf",

        "DejaVu Sans|Bold":
            "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2019.1.220/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf",

        "DejaVu Sans|Bold|Italic":
            "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2019.1.220/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf",

        "DejaVu Sans|Italic":
            "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2019.1.220/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf",
        "Kalpurush":
            "https://www.omicronlab.com/download/fonts/kalpurush.ttf",
        "SiyamRupali":
            "https://www.omicronlab.com/download/fonts/Siyamrupali.ttf"
    });
</script>

<script>
    var generatePDF = function () {
        kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#pdfReport"), {
            avoidLinks: true,
            paperSize: "A4",
            landscape: true,
            font: "14px 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, sans-serif, Kalpurush, SiyamRupali"
        }).then(function (group) {
            kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "Acr-Summary.pdf");
        });
    }
</script>
```

The view page of HTML is

[image]

Here you can see, in last column of first row unicode character is displayed. But when I generate pdf the view become like this. Unicode character become box.

[image]

I have tried several way. Any help will be appreciated.